# An exercise on set theory(ZFC)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_{1};A_{2};\dots;A_{n}$ befixed subsets of the set $X$. Assume that $A_{i}^{1}=A_{i}$, $A_{i}^{0}=X-A_{i}$. Every set of the form $A_{1}^{i_{1}}\cap A_{2}^{i_{2}}\cap\dots A_{n}^{i_{n}}$, where $i_{j}=0,1$ for $j=1,\dots,n$; Is called a constituent with respect to the sets $A_{1};A_{2};\dots;A_{n}$. If all the constituents are
non-empty, the sets $A_{1};A_{2};\dots;A_{n}$ are called independent.

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be the collection of those sets that can be obtained from $A_{1};A_{2};\dots;A_{n}$ using the operations union, intersection
and complementation $(\cup;\cap;\,\,^{c})$. Prove that every set $B\in\mathcal{H}$ can be represented uniquely as the union of constituents.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Take $X = \{0, 1\}$ and $A_0 = \{0\}$ and $A_1 = X$. Then $\{0\} = A_0 = A_0 \cap A_1$, so the decomposition is not unique.